# 7 - How to create a view using ApacheSolr?

Tags: views, search

How am I able to create a view using ApacheSolr as base in Drupal 7?

All I can see when creating a new View, is ApacheSolr localhost server which doesn't give me the fields that I need, found few links online but none of them helped! very confused!

I am using :

- Apache 7.x-1.0-rc4
- Drupal 7
- Views 7.x-3.5
- Apache Solr Search Integration 7.x-1.0-beta1

Comment: try the http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views module.

Comment: Thank you but that only gives me local host server option, I dont know how to create a page with the fields that I need?

Comment: I would for example lie to use Contextual filters to add other content fields to my search result as well but sadly it wont let me!

Comment: what apachesolr server are you using? first you have to select proper server - it should be enabled in your apachesolr settings. and then you can choose when creating views.

Comment: In my experience apachesolr is good for search results, but if you want a good and complete interaction with Views you should use search_api

Comment: search_api sounds very promising thank you. Although I still like to know how it is possible to extend the fields in the view. Many thanks

Comment: solr search api for 7 is flaky in my experience, lots of stability issues. even worse, the facet api doesn't work so great with solr and search api in 7 either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The various answers here do not mention the [apachesolr_views](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views) module, which has the advantage of working directly with  [Apache Solr Search Integration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr).  The Search API Solr module requires a distinct setup, and if you want to use both integrations simultaneously, it's [more complicated](http://drupal.org/node/1396496).  If you already have Apache Solr Search Integration working for you, I suggest taking the simpler approach.  You'll then get views right out of the box.
[image: Working view with apachesolr_views right out of the box]

Answer (score 4):

I add a full response.

If you want a full integration with Solr and Views you should use [Search api](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) with [Search Api Solr](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) (there several modules that work with Search Api, see the Search Api page).

You will be able to:

- create search pages (like normal search pages), with [Search Api Pages](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_page)
- create every type of view based on the Solr Index, using filters, relations, contextual filters
- add facet, with http://drupal.org/project/facetapi, to search pages and views

There are many usefule modules that work with Search Api: autocompletation, indexing files, create index on file taxonomies and users, spellcheck, sorts, ranges, saved searches etc.

Every day I use Search Api at work, for views and for default search, I think is the best solution.

Comment: [Current Search Links](http://drupal.org/project/current_search_links) (allowing individual search terms to be removed from a search) is another member of that family of modules worth knowing about. Be aware as others have said that the Search API stack is a bit flakey. There's only one module maintainer (!) and there are a few bugs, patches not committed, etc. Take some time to test thoroughly, and allow plenty of debugging time. When it works (which is most of the time), it's brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to the [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) module.

> This module provides a framework for easily creating searches on any
>   entity known to Drupal, using any kind of search engine.

The Views capabilities are excellent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the nature of the question, but creating a view in 7 with Apache Solr works great for me.  You have to first create an index and then when you go to create the new view the name of that index should show up in the list, ie "Show [ name of index ] sorted by..." .  From there you can create a table view or whatever.  If you are using Facet API then you can define facets on that index, which automatically creates blocks and you move those blocks into a region and have them only show up at the path that corresponds with the view you created.