# Apache Solr Framework with Views (for Facet Search)

Tags: views, search

**What I want**

I want to use the Apache Solr Search to:
1. built a Global Search with a customized Search Results Display
2. built a Facet Search for specific content types

**Problems**

Currently I'm trying to use the Apache Solr Framework Module:
https://drupal.org/project/ApacheSolr

So my first question: As far as I can see, this module has no native integration with views, right?

As a result I installed the "Apache Solr Views Integration" Module:
https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views

But when I create a view of the new typ "Apache Solr .." I am experiencing different problems:
1. Not all fields are available (for the facet search I only need to display specific fields)
2. It is not possible to filter the Content Type (needed for the facet search)
3. It is not possible to set the ouput to "rendered entity" (needed for the global search!)

Does anybody know to achieve the result that I want? What are your expieriences with the Apache Solr Framework? How do you integrate this with views?

Comment: did you ever get an answer for this?  I'm having similar issues...  my current hunch is that all content must be indexed by solar before the fields for each content type are available in Views...  however, I'm having (unrelated) issues getting all my content indexed.

Answer (score 1):

I have typically achieved this type of thing using the [Search API](https://drupal.org/project/search_api) module which provides ability to select which fields are indexed and thus exposed to Views in turn along with Apache Solr integration.

The Search API provides a great base onto which to build very powerful search applications.

Comment: I would highly recommend using search_api and search_api_solr as well.

Comment: Thank you both. Right now, we are not using Search API because we can't find a way to make attachments searchable, if the solr server is on a remote server installed. Is there a way with Search API to make attachements on a remote server searchable? e.g. like this module: https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_attachments

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the search API to search attachments. [search_api_attachments module](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_attachments)

Seems that Search API is the prefered way to display search results within Views

> If you want a full integration with Solr and Views you should use Search api with Search Api Solr.  [see this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/45616/1563)

I've tried to use https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_viewson a recent project but it's lack of a way to display spelling suggestions in the View page has complicated that for me.

The choice between Solr and Search API backed by Solr can be difficult depending on your requirements, for example do you need to index Multilingual content ?